# Regarding Problem 5 on p. 71 of Bredon's Topology and Geometry

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory

Someone else asked this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141996/proving-that-two-given-functionally-structured-spaces-are-isomorphic) long ago. Sadly, no answer was provided.

I though the *natural* approach would be trying to show that $x\rightarrow x^{2}$ is an isomorphism of functionally structured spaces. However, I run into a wall every time.

**Does anyone know how to solve problem 5 on p.71 of Bredon's Topology and Geometry?**

Comment: Your did not link properly to the mentioned question.

Comment: Corrected, thanks

Comment: it seems that you have just to check that the inverse map is a homomorphism of functionally structured spaces.

Comment: That seems to be the crux of the matter. Check Remark 3 in the linked MO question. Not trivial at all.

Comment: well two things, isn't that derivative wrong? and 2 would not be a problem (you need $x^2-2$ to be zero), in case $\pm\sqrt 2$ would be which is not in $V$